# vim: "nnoremap <Leader>R :!for i in `grep -Rl <C-w> src/`; do ...; done;" does not send -Rl string. why?

Tags: bash, vim

I have this script:

```
nnoremap <Leader>R :!for i in `grep -Rl <C-w> src/`; do sed -i 's/<C-r><C-w>/<C-r><C-w>/g' $i; done;<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

it helps me all the times I need to change the name of a class, using sed. When I press "R", i see in the command line

```
:!for i in `grep - src/`; do sed -i 's/Class/Class/g' $i; done;
```

As you can see,

```
`grep - src/`
```

isnt

```
`grep -Rl Class src/`
```

as I expected. Someone could please show me how to fix this and tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the rest works (I didn't check), you must replace `<C-w>` with `<C-r><C-w>`.

```
:!for i in `grep <C-w> src/`; do sed -i 's/<C-r><C-w>/<C-r><C-w>/g' $i; done;
```

should be:

```
:!for i in `grep <C-r><C-w> src/`; do sed -i 's/<C-r><C-w>/<C-r><C-w>/g' $i; done;
```